# VBA using RandBetween

Tags: vba

Why I am getting an compilation error: "Sub or Function no defined" ?

```
Public Function generateCode() As String      
 generateCode = RandBetween(3, 12)
End Function
```

Comment: `generateCode = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(3, 12)`

Comment: Or use [rnd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/rnd-function)

Comment: @ScottCraner Sorry, didn't ment to steal your answer, was already typing when your comment came in.

Comment: @FunThomas no worries, I have no problem with someone expanding on on of my comments as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

`RandBetween` is not a build-in function in VBA, it is an Excel function. As long as you are programming for Excel, you can access Excel functions via `WorksheetFunction`, in your case `Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(3, 12)`